# Should I zero the allocated memory?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory

I am programming tcp socket and I'm using `struct sockaddr_in server_addr;` to set port etc. In some tutorials I have read that I should zero the memory of `server_addr` before using it. Should I? Is it posible that I'll get memory with some data which could cause problems? Is it different for linux and windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't initialize a reserved memory area it will contain any value that was stored there earlier. So it is always a good idea to "zero it", which means overwriting what ever was there with some value, in this case the null byte `\0`.

If you replace `malloc` with `calloc` this will be done for you automatically.

Regardless of if you do this it will not influence the values you read from the socket.

It will not matter if you do this on Windows or Linux/Unix: this is common behaviour for all environments.

Answer (score 4):

It's a good idea to do so, in particular in this case. These low-level socket `struct`s have zillions of little members in nested form. The `memset` ensures that none of them has garbage values. It's very easy, relatively efficient, and can clear hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Do you want to use it before you write it over or not? If you are sure you won't read from the memory before you overwrite it - you can leave the memory unzeroed (it would cost extra program-working time and would need more code - the less code, the better) otherwise you must initialize the memory with zeroes.